# Loading multiple webpack bundles correctly

Tags: javascript, webpack

tl;dr; how should you load multiple webpack bundle without littering your code with script tags

I've been looking into using webpack more however there seems to be a piece i'm missing when it comes to loading webpack bundles, up to now i've been using requirejs which allows you to split you code into modules (which i consider the equivalent of bundles in webpack) but requirejs allows you to require scripts by name in your code which is then mapped to a url in the config but with webpack you would just include a script tag onto the page which feels like it could get out of control quite easily as you would end up with scripts littered throughout the views of your application, and makes it more difficult to switch out bundles as instead of updating a single url you need to find and replace every occurance of that url, not the end of the world but it seems like i've either missed some functionality to make this easier or maybe it's an accepted difference between requirejs and webpack.

I should mention the none of the code bases i'm considering adding webpack too are single page applications so perhaps webpack is just not suited to this kind of environment?

Just to add a little bit of context to what i would intend this to be included in, our server side code uses a mvc pattern so it would look something like this

## page skelton/layout

```
<html>
<head><!-- stuff here --></head>
<body>
    <!-- some included view here -->
</body>
</html>
```

## view 1

```
<div>
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Currently it has this -->
    <script>
        require(['something'], function(s){ /* new s(); */ /* s(); */ /* etc */ });
    </script>
    <!-- and i'd imagine it would be like this with webpack -->
    <script src="my_bundle.js"></script>
</div>
```

## view 2

```
<div>
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Currently it has this -->
    <script>
        require(['something', 'another_thing'], function(s){ /* new s(); */ /* s(); */ /* etc */ });
    </script>
    <!-- and i'd imagine it would be like this with webpack -->
    <script src="my_bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="my_bundle2.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't entirely happy with the router approach as it would have effectivly meant having to duplicate our url rewriting config in javascript and duplicating import statements where pages share code and i'm not sure but the [import docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) seem to imply that any imported scripts would be included in the final bundle instead of dynamically loaded during page load which would mean a lot of code in the bundle that is unused most of the time.

it seems like the best approach for me would be to effectively create a simpler version of requirejs to load bundle files (example below) which would then allow me to keep a similar structure to the existing code, admittedly i might still look for a library instead of rolling my own loader but i haven't decided yet.

## Loader

```
class Loader{

  constructor(config){
    this.config = config;
  }

  load(modName){
    if(this.config.debug)console.log('loader - ', 'load called', arguments);

    if(!document.getElementById(modName)){
      if(this.config.debug)console.log('loader - ', 'loading new script', modName, this.config.map[modName]);

      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.id = modName;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = this.config.map[modName];
      script.async = true;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
  }

}

export default Loader;
```

## Loader Config

```
window.loader = new Loader({
  'debug': true,
  'map': {
    'something': '/scripts/bundle.js',
    'another_thing': '/scripts/bundle2.js'
  }
});
```

## View 1

```
<div>
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Currently it has this -->
    <script>
        require(['something'], function(s){ /* new s(); */ /* s(); */ /* etc */ });
    </script>
    <!-- which would change to (any of the callback code would be inside the bundle) -->
    <script>
        window.loader.load('something');
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I used webpack's [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) functionality in my singe page application to dynamically load bundles based on the route. This doesn't require you to litter script tags throughout your application necessarily. If you use a routing mechanism of any sort you can dynamically import the dependency when that route is accessed like so:

```
// Index
router.on(() => {

  import(/* webpackChunkName: "routeA" */ '../routes/routeA').then((module) => {
    // do something with your loaded module
  }).resolve();
});
```

[Dynamically loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) this 'root' style module, i.e. the root of a dependency tree bundled by webpack means you can only fetch it when you need to. This means the client will only fetch this bundle.js when you execute this route.

Using the dynamic imports requires the addition of the `chunkFilename` property in your webpack config:

```
output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
}
```

Edit: If you're using express.js you could do the same following its routing mechanism. Your best bet is to refer to the code splitting documentation provided by webpack (linked above).

Comment: so if i'm understanding correctly you would have bundle which is included in every page with all your routes that then loads the other required bundles? if that's correct is the routing functionality built into webpack or is that supplied by another library?

Comment: also is the comment in the import call a convention or does it have some kind of meaning? i've read [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) for lazy loading but that didn't seem to address it.

Comment: The comment is a special comment used by web pack code splitting to allocate a name to the bundled chunk. If blank it will generate a random name. What are you using as the server in your application?

Comment: Server side we using coldfusion (unfortunately :D ) with coldbox (for mvc functionality), i've included a rough example of what it would look like in my edit to the main question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have any experience with either frameworks. But you must have some code that defines what view to load for which url? That essentially is a route, mapping a URL to a function. Inside your function you dynamically import the module you need for that route and webpack will retrieve it for you in the browser.

Comment: i guess currently the views themselves act kind of like the router as they require the modules that they need and theirs no integration between front and back end code otherwise